# Apache: adding new subdomains?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to add a new subdomain to an existing site. I'm using Apache on Debian, with a number of working virtual hosts on the site already - not set up by me.

The `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file contains the following lines (incidentally `httpd.conf` exists but is empty, I don't know if that's significant):

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

In the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory, there is a whole bunch of files, called things like

```
forum.mysite.org
docs.mysite.org
```

Each of these files has a VirtualHost entry - e.g. `forum.mysite.org` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.mysite.org
    WSGIScriptAlias /var/docs/forum.wsgi
    ... etc
```

My question is this. To add a new subdomain, do I simply need to create a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` and set ServerName and WSGIScriptAlias appropriately? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: if all you want is to add a subdomain to an existent site, for example if the site was forum.mysite.org you could open that file and add bellow ServerName the follow ServerAlias new_sub_domain.mysite.org if ServerAlias already exist just go to the end of the line hit space and add the new subdomain, save and restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create a new file in /etc/apache2/sites-available, perhaps copying one of the previous files and modifying it. Then save (keeping to the already-present naming structure will probably help to keep things organised),

> a2ensite example.mysite.org

or whatever you've called the file will tell Apache to enable the site, automatically creating the symlink needed in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. Then

> /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

as pQd has already said.

Presumably DNS entries have been set up pointing *.mysite.org to the IP of the server or the FQDN mysite.org, otherwise you'll have to do this or add a new DNS record for each subdomain.mysite.org as well.

Answer (score 0):

pretty much it. usually in debian you have actual files in /etc/apache2/sites-available and sites-enabled directory contains only sym-links to earlier ones.

after any modifications tell apache about change in configs:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```